# How to change Date format in Oracle BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

While Running Report in BI Publisher , the excel output displays one of the date column value as '2009-06-03T18:44:32.000-07:00' .  but we wanted it to be simple as '2009-06-03' so that we can filter the particular column in the excel by Year, month,Date.

We used To_char function which gives the output as desired but we cannot filter the column as excel takes the values as text but not date.
And if we use TO_Date function in the Data model query , the out in excel is displayd in Canonical format-2009-06-03T18:44:32.000-07:00'

Please let me know how to fix this in BI publisher.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have the BI Publisher desktop add-in installed for Word, and that you are editing a Word rtf which you have set EBS to output into Excel.

You should have a text field where the Field Help Text is something like `<?DATE?>`.  The Text form field type needs to be set to `Date`, and the date format set to `yyyy-MM-dd` (or however you want it formatted).

Once you have all that set, it should work. If it's not, you may have something in the XML element not formatted correctly. If the Date element is not PERFECT it wont be able to format it. Here's an XML element example that should work. Make sure your's matches, or read the user guide for BI Publisher, it should help you too. `<DATE>2012-04-05T18:17:12.000+00:00</DATE>`

Comment: Hi EdHayes3 -      I am not using BI Publisher desktop add-in installed for word.

Comment: What are you using?

Comment: Hi EDHayes-  I am using Drag and drop report in BIP